# grouping tasks in org-agenda

Tags: org-agenda, org-super-agenda

Is there a way to show the tasks in the agenda list grouped by category? I mean in the task list view (when pressing `C-c a t`) rather than the week-agenda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[org-super-agenda](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-super-agenda)  can do this kind of grouping.  Just add `(:auto-category t)` to the `org-super-agenda-groups` list.

Something like

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
    '("t" "All TODOs groups by category" alltodo ""
        ((org-super-agenda-groups '((:auto-category t))))
    ))
```

Will generate a list of TODOs, grouped into sections by category.

Comment: As far as I can see, `org-super-agenda` groups the entries in the week-agenda rather than the task list. Is this not the case?

Comment: It works the same with both types.  I use it with the `alltodo` agenda, mostly because it's faster to use its `:discard` than `org-agenda-skip-function`

Answer (score 0):

To set it for the default todo agenda you can do:

```
(setq org-agenda-sorting-strategy
      (cons '(todo category-up priority-down) org-agenda-sorting-strategy))
```

Otherwise, define a custom agenda:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands      
      '(("c" "List TODOs grouped by category" alltodo ""
         ((org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(category-up priority-down))))))
```

Comment: Thanks. I know how to sort by category, but I wanted to group by categories like `org-super-agenda` does.

Comment: Ok, I was just suggesting a poor's man grouping.